# Mysql connection lost after a certain interval grails application

Tags: mysql, grails, datasource, jndi, connection-pooling

I am currently using **Grails-2.2.4** on my application, recently I've been facing a strange issue. In my production war, the application is frequently losing mysql connection after some period and the application requires a restart for the connection to work again and it works fine for another couple of days. 
I am using tomcat **jdbc-pool:7.0.47** and here is my here is my datasource properties

```
dataSource {
shard = false
pooled = true
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
properties {
    initialSize=5
    maxActive=50
    minIdle=5
    maxIdle=25
    maxWait = 10000
    maxAge = 10 * 60000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
    numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    validationInterval=15000
    testWhileIdle=true
    testOnBorrow=true
    testOnReturn=true
    jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
    defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    }
}
```

I have the same configuration in some other application and it has been running without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `autoreconnect` argument in your datasource URL:

```
dataSource {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true"
}
```

**Update**

Another reason could be your TCP firewall is dropping the connection after some time being idle. So you need to modify the TCP timeout settings. I'm giving an related doc for how to achieve this on Amazon EC2 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html. You can do it for your provider, that should be same.

Comment: Are your Grails application server and MySQL server are two different servers?

Comment: both are on different servers

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer. Let's try that if that is the problem